# Tried to use relative imports, and broke my import paths?

Tags: python, flask, importerror

I'm running a Flask server locally on my Mac.

**My project:**

```
project/my_lib/my_class.py  
project/testing/flask_server.py  
project/testing/something/test_class.py
```

At one point, I tried to get fancy with some relative imports to test a class in a different directory:

In **project/testing/something/test_class.py:**

```
from ..my_lib.my_class import MyClass
```

That gave me an error:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

So I backed out of that, but now I **can't get my Flask server to run**, even though I eliminated the new import code.

```
$ python testing/flask_server.py
```

Spits out this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing/flask_server.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 26, in <module>
    from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES, \
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 28, in <module>
    from urllib.request import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
ImportError: No module named request
```

Huh?

---

**UPDATE:**

The flask import error only happens in the directory the bad code was originally called from. That is, if I do

```
from flask import Flask
```

from anywhere in the **project/testing** dir, I get the import error, but if I do it in **project/** or anywhere else on my system, it's fine..?

---

**SOLUTION (PARTLY):**

I don't have an explanation as to why this happened, but I did the following to fix it:

1. Created a new **testing/** directory and copied the files from the old one into it. The old **testing/** directory had to be deleted- it was basically corrupted.
2. Did my cross-directory imports using absolute instead of relative paths.

(By the way, I tried to retrace my steps to reproduce the relative import error but was unable to, so I'm not sure of either the cause or solution to this whole thing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have your own `urllib2` python file in your system path, perhaps in the local directory. Don't do that, as it breaks `werkzeug` (and other python code).

To be compatible with both python 2 and 3, `werkzeug` uses constructs like:

```
try:
    from urllib2 import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
except ImportError: # pragma: no cover
    from urllib.request import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
```

The `from urllib2 import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header` line could throw a `ImportError` exception if you have a local `urllib2.py` module or `urllib2/__init__.py` package that masks the standard library file.

Because the first import throws an `ImportError`, the second line is executed, which *also* fails because the `urllib.request` package is only available on Python 3.

From your project, run the following code to diagnose *where* you have that module:

```
import urllib2
print urllib2.__file__
```

If that still works, then run:

```
from urllib2 import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
```

as it could be that `urllib2` indirectly imports something that you masked. `urllib2` uses `from urlib import ...` statements for example, so a local `urllib` module would also break the import.

It is important that you do this *from your flask project*, just before the `from flask import Flask` line.

Comment: Thanks- so this is what `print urllib2.__file__` yeilds: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.pyc`. It's not local, and I'm running the same code that worked before I caused the import errors. So I'm still unclear as to why my previously working code is now broken, and on how to fix it.

Comment: Try the `from urllib2 import ...` line next

Comment: The `from urllib2 import ...` line does not error (So why is the `from urllib.request import...` line even being called?!)

Comment: I really appreciate your effort on this. Unfortunately after I deleted the directory and started over (as described above), I was unable to even reproduce the errors, so we won't have a definitive answer on this. However I'll give you credit because it was a good answer nonetheless.