# conda and pip not working at all

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

I am on OS X 10.11.2, Anaconda Python 2.7.10.

I was installing some dependencies, and suddenly, my `conda` command started not working at all. Many people suggest `conda install python=2.7.10` but when I try that (or any command, even just `conda`) I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/Can/anaconda/bin/conda", line 5, in 
>       sys.exit(main())   File "/Users/Can/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py",
>   line 106, in main
>       from conda.cli import conda_argparse   File "/Users/Can/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       from conda.cli.find_commands import find_commands, find_executable   File
>   "/Users/Can/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/find_commands.py",
>   line 9, in 
>       from conda.utils import memoized   File "/Users/Can/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/utils.py", line
>   10, in 
>       import tempfile   File "/Users/Can/anaconda/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in 
>       import io as _io   File "/Users/Can/anaconda/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in 
>       import _io ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Can/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2):
>   Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder   Referenced
>   from: /Users/Can/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so   Expected
>   in: dynamic lookup

How can I repair `conda`, without using `conda` itself (as I can't)?

**UPDATE:** I've completely uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda. It still gives the same error. I've tried `pip` and it also fails with the same error. I verify it's Anaconda's pip as `which pip` returns `/Users/Can/anaconda2/bin/pip`. Why is Anaconda broken?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, it is successfully fixed by just replacing the _io.so file.

```
sudo find / -name _io.so
```

copy the path of the _io.so file which **DOES NOT** belong to python-2.7.11. For example, copy the path of _io.so which is under python-2.7.5:
 /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so

Replace the '/Users/Can/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so' file with the _io.so that you just found.

```
cp /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so /Users/Can/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/
```

Then it will work.

Comment: +1.  I ran into this issue trying to run Splunk on OS X 10.11.3 with Python 2.7.11.  Copying _io.so from Splunk's own packaged copy of Python 2.7 into the 2.7.11 folder solved it.

Comment: thank you. this issue has been bothering me for some time now!